# At reboot, which address an IPv6 host will acquire?

Tags: networking, ip-address, ipv6

After the reboot, the host will be autoconfigured by using Router Advertisements, ok, but in simply words: what will be the new address? Build from the Router prefix and the remaining part generated casually or based on the host MAC address? What are differences by generating a link local address with stateless configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking depends greatly on which OS the host is running. With a pure SLAAC implementation, the IPv6 address Interface ID (global and link local) is generated from the MAC address, which is then appended to the prefix in the RAs for the global address, and appended to the link-local prefix for the link local address. If your OS uses SLAAC with privacy extensions or random address generation, things are different.

There are RFCs for how to do any and all of the above, but a discussion of all of them is too large for this site. You should search for `rfc ipv6 slaac`, `rfc ipv6 privacy extension`, and `rfc ipv6 random address`. You could also search for what your particular OS uses to generate IPv6 addresses.

Comment: Most likely I was referring to the pure SLAAC, thank you!